# image upload is not working on meteor.

Tags: meteor

image upload is not working amazon ec2 instance. it is working fine on local machine but not working on amazon ec2 instance.

```js
Meteor.startup(function(){
   UploadServer.init({
      tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
      uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/uploads/',
      getDirectory: function(file, formData){
          return formData.contentType;
      },finished: function(file, folder, formFields){
          Users.update({email:ServerSession.get('email')},{$set:{image:file.name}});
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: my upload folder permission is set to 777. but still image upload is not working. i am getting error like    " POST http://ec2-52-39-139-119.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET "

Comment: please help me to fix this issue ASAP.